# How to change default downloader on Firefox

Tags: firefox, uget, downloaders

I want to change default downloader of Firefox because it is very slow. I want to set uGet. I installed uGet downloader, but when I click some download link it start with Firefox's own downloader. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The following info is outdated, please see "Update" at the bottom

You may use the ["uGet Integration" extension by Gobinath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ugetintegration/) to replace the default download manager by uGet.

This extension requires ["uGet Chrome Wrapper"](https://slgobinath.github.io/uget-chrome-wrapper/) package to be installed. To install the package from [Gobinath's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eslgobinath/+archive/ubuntu/uget-chrome-wrapper) run the following commands first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper
sudo apt update
sudo apt install uget-chrome-wrapper
```

Then install the extension from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ugetintegration/). Once it is installed, click on the uGet icon and toggle on "Interrupt downloads":
[image]
(screenshot source: uGet Integration's homepage at addons.mozilla.org)

---

#### Update:

In 2018, `uget-chrome-wrapper` has been adopted by uGet team as an official add-on and renamed `uget-integrator` and so `uget-chrome-wrapper` is discontinued. Therefore, uninstall `uget-chrome-wrapper` and install `uget-integrator`.

To remove `uget-chrome-wrapper`, run

```
sudo apt remove uget-chrome-wrapper
```

To remove Gobinath's old PPA, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper
sudo apt update
```

Then add the new PPA for uGet Team by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uget-team/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Finally, install `uget-integrator` by running

```
sudo apt install uget-integrator
```

Also update the Firefox add-on to version 2.1.2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Just install [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox AddOn and enjoy!!!!

is the fastest and easiest way to download high speed with more segments
I even use it on My Mac rather than other downloads software

Comment: DownloadThemAll! is not compatible with the recent versions of Firefox (57+).

Comment: @pomsky if you install the former version of Firefox and install dTa then update the firefox itself you still have dTa I got 58.0.2 and no issues